# Allowable jBoss 7 session characters

Tags: session, jboss, jboss7.x

I couldn't find information on the algorithm used by jBoss 7 to generation session IDs and I need to know what characters are possible. I noticed that sometimes the session ID has characters like: + * .  etc... This seems different than jBoss 5 which was only alphanumeric.

Can you help me determine what characters are allowed for a jBoss 7 generated session ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session ID generation is handled by [org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase](http://source.jboss.org/browse/JBossWeb/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/session/ManagerBase.java?hb=true#to583). The general format is as follows:

```
<encodedSessionId>.<jvmRoute>
```

ID encoding is based on:

```
SESSION_ID_ALPHABET = System.getProperty("org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.SESSION_ID_ALPHABET", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+_")
```

The `jvmRoute` part is usually environment dependent (it may be used for handling [session affinity](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/engine.html#Attributes) in a cluster).

Comment: Thanks very much, that's helpful. So really it is alphanumeric with the following characters +(plus sign)  _ (underscore) and . (dot)